# SQL query to select multiple values

Tags: sql, db2, case

I'm creating a traffic report for my company but I'm really stuck on this piece of code..

I have a report number, and type of accidents denoted by number i.e; 1-slight, 2-serious, 3-fatal and 4-not injured.

usually an accident report contains more than one number, for instance:

a report number 2014123 has a driver with serious injury '2', passenger Not Injured '4'.

so when i fire the select query where report number=2014123 , i get two records, one with '2' injury and the other with '4'.

in the above scenario, the accident is treated as 'Serious' since it contains '2'. '4' is not considered since the passenger is not injured. injury codes with (slight, serious, fatal) are treated higher than (not injured).

How can I generate the report with serious injury (i.e; code '2') and the injury count as '2'(since two records)?

Methods I have tried:

I tried with the SQL Case statement:

```
(Case WHEN InjuryCode IN ('1','2','4') THEN 'Serious'
WHEN InjuryCode IN ('1','2','3','4') THEN 'FATAL'
WHEN InjuryCode IN ('1','4') THEN 'SLIGHT'

ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END) AS ACCIDENT_STATUS
```

but all i got was duplicating and incorrect data.

the injury code is given preference in the following manner:
3>2>1>4

eg: an accident with contains injurycode as:

```
1,4- slight
2,4- serious
3,4- fatal
```

1,2,3,4-fatal (because 3 is the highest injury code) etc etc..

I hope this doesn't get you confused, but kindly bear with me, ,i was totally confused at the beginning, but i am actually getting the picture now, although without a solution, please help!

EDIT (the full query from the comment):

```
SELECT REPORTNUMBER, INJURYCODE,
       (CASE WHEN InjuryCode IN ('1','2','4') THEN 'Serious'
             WHEN INJURYCODE IN ('1','2','3','4') THEN 'FATAL'
             WHEN INJURYCODE IN ('1','4') THEN 'SLIGHT' ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
       END) AS ACCIDENT_STATUS
FROM ACCIDENTS
WHERE REPORTNUMBER=20140302
```

Comment: Please show the structure of the data that you are accessing and/or the full query with the case statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Sure, SELECT REPORTNUMBER,
INJURYCODE,
CASE(WHEN InjuryCode IN ('1','2','4') THEN 'Serious'
WHEN INJURYCODE IN ('1','2','3','4') THEN 'FATAL'
WHEN INJURYCODE IN ('1','4') THEN 'SLIGHT'

ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END) AS ACCIDENT_STATUS

FROM ACCIDENTS WHERE REPORTNUMBER=20140302

GO

Comment: ADVICE: You should not put digits in quotes. Either it is a number which doesn't use quotes, or it is a string, so you should avoid using meaningless digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `injuryCode` suggests that you need an `Injury` table (if you don't have one already).  Ideally, this includes some sort of severity column that you could order by - something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Injury (injuryCode CHAR(1),
                     severity INTEGER,
                     description VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO Injury VALUES ('1', 1, 'Slight'),
                          ('2', 2, 'Serious'),
                          ('3', 3, 'Fatal'),
                          ('4', 0, 'Not Injured');
```

Strictly speaking, what you were attempting before was sorting based on an apparent id of the injury - the only thing ids should be used for is joins, and should otherwise be considered random/undefined values (that is, the actual value is unimportant - it's whether there's anything *connected to it* that's important).  The fact that these happen to be numerical codes (apparently stored as character data - this is perfectly acceptable) is immaterial.

Regardless, with a sorting table defined, we can now safely query the data:

```
SELECT AggregateAccident.reportNumber, Injury.injuryCode, Injury.description, 
       AggregateAccident.victimCount
FROM (SELECT Accidents.reportNumber, MAX(Injury.severity) as severity, 
             COUNT(*) as victimCount
      FROM Accidents
      JOIN Injury
        ON Injury.injuryCode = Accidents.injuryCode
      GROUP BY Accidents.reportNumber) AggregateAccident
JOIN Injury
  ON Injury.severity = AggregateAccident.severity
ORDER BY AggregateAccident.reportNumber
```

(And [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87f9b/4).  Thanks to Turophile for the skeleton.  Using SQL Server, but this should work on any RDBMS).

---

## EDIT:

If you can't create a permanent table, you can create a temporary one:

```
WITH Injury AS (SELECT a AS injuryCode, b AS severity, c AS description
                FROM (VALUES ('1', 1, 'Slight'),
                             ('2', 2, 'Serious'),
                             ('3', 3, 'Fatal'),
                             ('4', 0, 'Not Injured')) I(a, b, c))
SELECT AggregateAccident.reportNumber, Injury.injuryCode, Injury.description, 
       AggregateAccident.victimCount
FROM (SELECT Accidents.reportNumber, MAX(Injury.severity) as severity, 
             COUNT(*) as victimCount
      FROM Accidents
      JOIN Injury
        ON Injury.injuryCode = Accidents.injuryCode
      GROUP BY Accidents.reportNumber) AggregateAccident
JOIN Injury
  ON Injury.severity = AggregateAccident.severity
ORDER BY AggregateAccident.reportNumber
```

(And [updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20e51/1))
The `WITH` clause constructs what's known as a Common Table Expression (CTE), and is basically an inline view or temporary table definition.  This could also be done with a subquery, but as I reference `Injury` twice, using a CTE means I only have to write the contained information once (in cases where the CTE is the result of some other query, this may help performance, too).  Most recent/current RDBMSs support this functionality (notably, MySQL does not), including DB2.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! Yes, it makes perfect sense when a severity column is added like this, however, I do not have rights to create or alter the table as it is controlled by the client DBA.. Hence, I was trying if there are any methods without creating the table.

Comment: Yup this one really helped me!!! I had to download the output from my office and load it into my local temp server after which i was able to generate the reports accordingly.. Thanks for your help and much thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (Not tested).

```
SELECT REPORTNUMBER,
       CASE INJURYCODE 
           WHEN 1 THEN 'SLIGHT' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Serious'
           WHEN 3 THEN 'FATAL'
           ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
       END ACCIDENT_STATUS,
       INJURYCOUNT
FROM (
   SELECT REPORTNUMBER, 
          MAX(CASE INJURYCODE WHEN 4 THEN 0 ELSE INJURYCODE END) INJURYCODE, 
          COUNT(1) INJURYCOUNT,
   FROM ACCIDENTS
   GROUP BY REPORTNUMBER
)
```

Comment: > Hello,i tried the above code without the report count(not running). > With your code,I got this output:
`code`ReportNumber Accident Status
20131 Serious
20131 SLIGHT
20132 SLIGHT
20133 SLIGHT
20135 FATAL
20136 Serious
20136 SLIGHT
20137 FATAL
20138 SLIGHT
20139 FATAL
201310 Serious
201310 SLIGHT

The reports 20131, 20136, 201310 has 2 records with 'Serious' and 'Slight'.Since the serious is higher than slight,i wish the report to consider accident as 'Serious' not slight.So is there anyway to override this?
Fatal accidents>Serious accidents>Slight accidents>Not injured
Thanks for your time

Comment: Noone can really help you without seeing your actual table definition and data (in the form of the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements). Good luck.

Comment: Sorry mustaccio, I do not have the exact table definiton for the  table. As it it created from the client side, I am permitted only to access the database.. Although from using the table, I do know the data types for the fields for the table and how the table definition looks like: `code CREATE TABLE ACCIDENTS(A_DATE DATETIME, REPORTNUMBER VARCHAR(50), INJURYCODE CHAR(1), A_INJURY_ENGLISH VARCHAR(50)); code`.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to improve your skills.

If you stored the injury code as a number like this:

```
 0 = Not injured
 1 = Slight
 2 = Serious
 3 = Fatal
```

Then you could use this clear and simple SQL:

```
select reportnumber, max(injurycode) as injurycode, count(*) as involved
from accidents
group by reportnumber
```

Here is a fiddle to illustrate it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87faf/1

Comment: ... And then somebody decides to add `5 = Moderate` (should be between `Slight` and `Serious`).  Essentially, you're relying on the id of the injury level to tell you its severity; this is like expecting an `Employee` table to have hierarchy sorted based on employee id...

Comment: @turophile: Thanks for the advice Turophile! But I do not have permission for altering the database and their injurycodes, I am currently assigned to develop the software with access only for retrieving the data. But,, this advice is Perfect, I would have followed your steps if I were the DBA..

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, you are right, but any real system would have another table to translate codes into descriptions - much like you tried to do with your answer, possibly with a ranking column to give them the correct order in the output.